# How to union two tables with different col number ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run this query :

```
SELECT firstName , secondName , lastName 
   FROM
       (SELECT firstName,secondName,lastName FROM table1

        UNION

        SELECT firstName,NULL,NULL FROM table2

       )resutls
```

I want add two Null columns to the second test, How could I do that ?

or duplicate the firstName twice - >

```
SELECT firstName , secondName , lastName 
 FROM
   (SELECT firstName,secondName,lastName FROM table1

    UNION

    SELECT firstName,firstName,firstName FROM table2

   )resutls
```

I want to add two more cols to the second select, because table2 has just one col(first name) , and the union will not work if I choose just one col.

Comment: Ah i had some mistake in the query nevermind, ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be this:

```
SELECT firstName , secondName , lastName 
 FROM
   (SELECT firstName,secondName,lastName FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT firstName, NULL as secondName, NULL as lastName FROM table2
   ) resutls
```

Use the alias of column name to treat it as a new column for second table.

This will work for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT firstName , secondName , lastName 
FROM
(SELECT firstName as fistname ,secondName as secondname ,lastName as lastname FROM table1

 UNION

 SELECT firstName as firstname,firstName as  '' ,firstName as '' FROM table2

 )
```

this will gibe u the name of column as null